# PowerShell script execution from {app} failing in Inno Setup, while an execution from {tmp} is working

Tags: powershell, inno-setup

My installer runs a PowerShell script to create certificates upon installation. In the `[Files]` section, I copy the two PowerShell scripts (one to install, one to uninstall):

```
[Files]
Source: "MyApp\Certs.ps1"; DestDir: "{tmp}\Neogen"; Flags: ignoreversion; \
    Permissions: everyone-full              
Source: "MyApp\UninstallCerts.ps1"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; \
    Permissions: everyone-full
```

The script to install the certificates uses a temp directory, and the uninstall script uses the app directory, which typically puts it into the `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp` folder. I can confirm that the uninstall script is being put into the correct folder.

When I uninstall the application, the certificates are not being uninstalled. The script looks like this:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object { $_.FriendlyName -match 'MyCert' } | Remove-Item
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\Root | Where-Object { $_.FriendlyName -match 'MyCert' } | Remove-Item
```

If I open a PowerShell window with administrator permissions and go to the `C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApp` folder to manually run the script, the script does work – the certificates are removed. It's just running the uninstall process from the Add / Remove program window where it fails.

My uninstall code in Inno Setup looks like this:

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "powershell.exe"; \
  Parameters: "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File """"{app}\UninstallCerts.ps1 ""{app}"" """""; \
  Flags: runhidden; RunOnceId: "MyAppId"
```

What am I missing when trying to run this PowerShell script when uninstalling?

Here is the syntax for how the certificate creation script (which does run successfully) is executed:

```
[Run]
Filename: "powershell.exe"; \
  Parameters: "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File """"{tmp}\Certs.ps1 ""{commonappdata}"" """""; \
   Flags: runhidden
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that the `{app}` contains spaces (`Program Files`?), while `{tmp}` does not. Your syntax does not handle paths with spaces correctly.

This is the [correct syntax](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=params):

```
[Run]
Filename: "powershell.exe"; \
  Parameters: "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""{tmp}\Certs.ps1"" ""{commonappdata}""";\ 
  Flags: runhidden

[UninstallRun]
Filename: "powershell.exe"; \
  Parameters: "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""{app}\UninstallCerts.ps1"" ""{app}"""; \
  Flags: runhidden; RunOnceId: "MyAppId"
```

---

*The `"""""` you have in your syntax is noop. It passes `""` to PowerShell, which treats is as nothing.*

Answer (score 0):

Inno setup dont Understand system32 but sysnative.
use parameter for [run] et [Uninstalrun]

Filename: "C:\Windows\Sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"; 
Parameters: "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""{app}\UninstallCerts.ps1"" ""{app}"""; 
Flags: runhidden; RunOnceId: "MyAppId"